# What is this Dead By Daylight icon?

Tags: dead-by-daylight

[image]

The second one from the left. I was watching a playthrough, and don't recognize that death symbol. Can someone tell me what it is?

Comment: That's for disconnecting or quiting the game they didn't die but they left the match

Answer (score 8):

The icon is not a death symbol but is a symbol to show that the player has disconnected or left the match.